# Elastic Search use multiple indexes and routing

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elastic cluster setup so that there are specific indices for a particular set of documents with id 1234 so the index will be index_2020_02_1234 for documents for customer 1234 in Feb but also have index_2020_02_OTHER for documents for other customers, as customer 1234 has the majority of the documents.  For the 'OTHER' indices we have routing using the customer ID.

I would like to search all indices for multiple customers i.e. customer 1234 and 5678.

As indices for customer 1234 doesn't have routing I am unable to use the indeices specific search i.e. /index_2020_02_1234,index_2020_02_OTHER/_search?routing=5678 as index_2020_02_1234 doesn't have routing.

I was wondering if there is a way to build up the Search Query body to do this so I can call /_search endpoint?

I know you can have:

```
"query": {
    "terms": {
        "_index": ["index_2020_02_1234", "index_2020_02_OTHER"] 
    }
}
```

and

```
"query": {
    "terms": {
        "_routing": ["5678"] 
    }
}
```

I need a combination of _index and _routing in the query.  Is this possible?

Would something like work:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "terms": {
                    "_index": ["index_2020_02_1234"] 
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "_index": ["index_2020_02_1234"],
                    "_routing": ["5678"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can add same alias to both indices so that you can search with an alias instead of index name.

Checkout Elasticsearch [index alias API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-add-alias.html)

In your case, you can index all users data into the same index, then create [user-based alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-add-alias.html#add-alias-api-user-ex) to search for a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution where I build upon the query with:

```
{
  “query”: {
    “bool”: {
      "should": [
        {
            "terms": {
                "_index": [
                    "index_2020_02_1234",
                    "index_2020_01_1234"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
             "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "_index": [
                                "index_2020_02_OTHER",
                                "index_2020_01_OTHER"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "_routing": [
                                5678,
                                9012
                        ]
                    }
                ]
             }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```